# Bootstrap Popover not reponsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

The popover does not display the image correctly when opened for the first time.

Any idea how I can make sure that it always displays correct?

https://jsfiddle.net/n2Lfro30/1/

This is the button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-rel="popover" title="<strong>Heading</strong>" data-placement="right" data-content="<img src='https://picsum.photos/400'>"> Click me </button>
```

this is the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-rel=popover]').popover({
      html: true,
      trigger: "hover"
    });
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use popover template property to make image responsive inside the popover also use `img-fluid` class to img tag.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('[data-rel=popover]').popover({
          html: true,
          trigger: "hover",
          template: `<div class="popover p-2" role="popover">
                      <div class="popover-arrow"></div>
                      <div class="popover-inner"><h4>Heading</h4></div>
                      <img src="https://picsum.photos/400" alt="Image" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>`
        });
      })
```

```css
img{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://homylive.com/erp/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://homylive.com/erp/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://homylive.com/erp/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-rel="popover" title="<strong>Heading</strong>" data-placement="right"> Click me </button>
```

Comment: still displays wrong the first time opened

Comment: Nope here is just working fine.

Comment: Don't use data-content in button tag now

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fv67n358/ does not work with the fiddle provided in question

Comment: You are using older bootstrap version use latest one bootstrap 5

Comment: the project is v3.3.5 else i wouldnt be asking :)

Comment: the fiddle is also using 3.3.5

Comment: Okay then use a css property to img tag i.e. `img{width:100%;}` it will fix your problem

Comment: use this property in css section

Comment: I also updated the answer as well check it now.

Comment: first time opening the arrow is still not in the right place

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the image to be responsive inside the container. For starters, add the styles `width:100%; height:auto` to your image to see what that does. (And then I'd recommend refactoring by using css in place of the inline style.)

```
<img src='https://picsum.photos/400' style='width:100%; height:auto'>
```

Using bootstrap's styles, it would be-

```
<img src='https://picsum.photos/400' class='img-responsive'>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ho2btzga/